# Can PHPExcel auto-fit based on a single cell value?

Tags: width, phpexcel

In PHPExcel, is it possible to auto-fit a column based on the value of only a single cell?

Say you have a heading in cell A1, you often don't want that auto-sized as it's to big. So you may just want to auto-fit based on A2, B2, C2, etc. Unfortunately `getColumnDimension('A1')->setAutoSize(true)` doesn't do the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, autosize works based on all the cells in a column because it applies to the column.

If you want to set the column width in any other way, you'd need to write your own function to calculate the maximum width of all the cells you wanted in that column, and then set the column width to that value.

Comment: That's a shame. That is a valuable Excel function that I use a lot, so will look to make an 'enhancement request' to the PHPExcel guys. Any tips on where to even start with a manual function?

Comment: I am the PHPExcel guy, and to be honest I don't think there'd be a great deal of demand for this modification; Tips on where to start? Look at the calculateColumnWidths() method for the Worksheet object, which calls on the PHPExcel_Shared_Font::calculateColumnWidth() method to calculate the width for each individual cell in an autosize column.

Comment: I'd be surprised if not many people used it direct through Excel, personally I'd be lost without it! Thanks for the starting point, I will have a look and see what I can come up with.